# find the coordinate of a point with given distance from a given line.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Given a line with coordinates $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ have a distance $\overline A$.
Now, with a given distance $\overline B$ from the point $(a,b)$ , I want to get the coordinates $(x,y)$ where distance $\overline B$ ends.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Yan Co try the formula $Distance = \sqrt {({x_1} - {y_1})^2 + ({x_2} -{y_2})^2 }$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parametric form of line.

$$x= a+ R(\dfrac{c-a}{A}), y=a+R(\dfrac{d-b}{A})$$

Now if you put R=B and R=-B, you will get two points on the line which is your answer.